# perl regex - quantifier * not greedy enough to pickup the newline at end of string

Tags: regex, perl

Is it not quantifier * , greedy ? Should not `\s*` match 0 or more occurence of white spaces,and which in turn would match everything till end of the given input string ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $input="Name :       www.devserver.com\n";
$input=~s/\w+.:\s*//;  # /s* should not it match everthing till \n at the end ?
print $input;
```

Please help me understand this behaviour.

Comment: `\w+.:\s*` will match `"Name_:______"`. It stops before the `"www"`, and never reaches the end `\n` anyway.

Comment: None of the characters in "www.devserver.com" match `\s`

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it. `*` would match zero or more occurence of a pattern right. In that case would not it be greedy to match all characters from its starting point to the end ( i.e. `\n` here )

Comment: @chidori: `\s*` would match all *whitespace* characters, and will stop as soon as it sees a non-whitespace char.  "www.devserver.com" is not whitespace, and `\s*` thus stops matching as soon as it hits the first "w".

Comment: @chidori: To add to cHao's answer: The term "greedy" in this context means "Grab everything that you can... but no more!" Greedy as the expression "\s*" may be, it's not allowed to grab anything but a contiguous ("consecutive") sequence of spaces, or nothing at all.

Comment: OK.. :) I was under the impression that \s* would keep on running and matching all chuck of characters until it finds the last whitespace character. I guess i misinterpreted the definition for greedy :)

Comment: `# echo "Naame :  www.devserver.com" | perl -pe 's/a*//'
Naame :  www.devserver.com`

Again , Why does this one-liner does not replace `aa` in input ?

Comment: That one is a bug and you should report it.

Comment: No need to worry - I have reported it for you

Comment: A bug ? i was under an assumption regex engine processes it a different way. And for some reason it settles at the starting line. 
`# echo "Naame : www.devserver.com" | perl -pe 's/a*/>REPLACED</'`
**>REPLACED<Naame : www.devserver.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s*` will match only a string consisting entirely of characters of the same class (namely, whitespace).
In your case, there is `www.devserver.com` between the leading and trailing spaces.

You may have tried to use `.` class instead of `\s`:

```
$input=~s/\w+.:.*//;
```

This also wouldn't touch the trailing newline! According to [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> To simplify multi-line substitutions, the "." character never matches a newline unless you use the /s modifier, which in effect tells Perl to pretend the string is a single line--even if it isn't.

So, wrapping it up: the behavior you are expecting can be reproduced with the following substitution:

```
$input=~s/\w+.:.*//s;
```